# Modelling experimental results with different end values

Tags: modeling

l have battery data, which shows the capacity fade as a function of the number of cycles , l would like to use this data to build a single model. However, the experimental data does not have the same lifespan.
[image]

Comment: Why is this a problem? What exactly do you want the model for?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to CV! A possible solution would be to use a [hierarchical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_hierarchical_modeling), in which you first draw the random variable corresponding to the lifespan, and then use it to model the link between $N$ and $Q$.

The higher level variable $x$ corresponding to the lifespan can be drawn as $x \sim p_{\theta}(x)$ (where $p_{\theta}$ is a probability distribution which parameters $\theta$ can be fitted on your observations). Then, based on your data you can define a (possibly deterministic) function $Q = f(N,x)$.